# Docker Desktop 3.2.2 on Window 10 Home crashes with error "error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running"

Tags: windows, docker, windows-10, docker-desktop

The docker containers that I am running seem to run fine on my macbook, but when running on my Windows 10 Home PC the Docker Engine will break.

When I try to use the Docker CLI it will fail to connect and claim that docker isn't running, even if docker is running.

I will run something like `docker ps` and I will recieve back the following error message:

```
error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/ib/json: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iB79F.jpg) is a screenshot saying that docker is running but the daemon is down.

Edit:

Here is the docker daemon log `C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Docker\log.txt`

```
[07:01:09.712][VpnKit            ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: Connected Ethernet interface f6:16:36:bc:f9:c6
[07:01:09.712][VpnKit            ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: UDP interface connected on 172.217.165.138
[07:02:02.548][VpnKitBridge      ][Info   ] msg="disconnected data connection: multiplexer is offline"
[07:02:02.552][WslKeepAlive      ][Info   ] wsl keep-alive stopped
[07:02:02.552][WslKeepAlive      ][Warning] stopped unexpectedly
[07:02:02.552][VpnKit            ][Error  ] vpnkit.exe: Vmnet.Server.listen: read EOF so closing connection
[07:02:02.552][VpnKit            ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: Vmnet.Server.disconnect
[07:02:02.552][VpnKit            ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: Vmnet.Server.listen returning Ok()
[07:02:02.552][VpnKit            ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: TCP/IP stack disconnected
[07:02:02.553][GoBackendProcess  ][Warning] msg="ignored error: EOF"
[07:02:02.553][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="DNS: UDP server has shutdown"
[07:02:02.553][GoBackendProcess  ][Warning] msg="Resyncer ports: while watching docker events: unexpected EOF"
[07:02:02.553][GoBackendProcess  ][Warning] msg="Resyncer volumes/noop: while watching docker events: unexpected EOF"
[07:02:02.556][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] msg="error copying response body from Docker:  unexpected EOF"
[07:02:02.556][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] msg="error closing response body from Docker:  unexpected EOF"
[07:02:02.556][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] msg="proxy << GET /v1.41/containers/fd15363049350ab0341b468a0fb771e3933967885d8a6273ce62bdf5497ba225/logs?follow=1&stderr=1&stdout=1&tail=all (7h51m40.4693942s)\n"
[07:02:02.556][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] msg="error copying response body from Docker:  unexpected EOF"
[07:02:02.556][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] msg="error closing response body from Docker:  unexpected EOF"
[07:02:02.556][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] msg="proxy << GET /v1.41/containers/1d1c26b0fa8e36173cc7fb94e74c28db531c859c3873c74aaf7acac1c6be93b6/logs?follow=1&stderr=1&stdout=1&tail=all (7h51m31.3039328s)\n"
[07:02:02.571][VpnKitBridge      ][Info   ] msg="Proxy filesystem-test: context is done before proxy is established"
[07:02:02.571][VpnKitBridge      ][Info   ] msg="Proxy filesystem-event: context is done before proxy is established"
[07:02:02.572][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="received new cli usage: {Command:logs Context:moby Status:success Source:cli}"
[07:02:02.576][LinuxWSL2Engine   ][Warning] Distro stopped with exit code 1
[07:02:02.578][LinuxWSL2Engine   ][Info   ] Stopping windows side processes
[07:02:02.598][DockerCliAPIServer][Info   ] Killing existing docker with PID 10496
[07:02:02.647][DockerCliAPIServer][Info   ] Killing existing docker with PID 8856
[07:02:02.647][DockerCliAPIServer][Info   ] Killing existing docker with PID 2788
[07:02:02.647][VpnKitBridge      ][Error  ] Process died
```

Comment: check [this](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/). Try troubleshooting, log file or enable debugging.

Comment: Thanks Anuj, I've added some details from the logs

Comment: Now check [this](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/8049). It says the config,json file is probably corrupted.

Comment: I deleted config.json (its contents was `{"credsStore":"desktop","stackOrchestrator":"swarm"}`) and then restarted Docker Desktop.

Comment: Happens to me from time to time. if restarting docker doesn't help, I always fixing it by switching to windows containers and back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that it's a problem with the Docker release version so I uninstalled and then installed an older version of Docker Desktop found [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/#docker-desktop-310).

If I don't come back (and update) to this answer then you can assume that it worked for me.

Update 1: Changing to an older docker did not solve it. I now believe that one of the containers was running out of memory. I will test and report back....

Update 2: I had 3 docker containers running. I believe that 1 of the containers was causing the docker engine to crash. After I removed the `multiprocessing` module from that docker container, the docker engine no longer crashes. It might be
1 of 3 things:

1. Windows 10 Home doesn't handle dockerized multiprocessing well.
2. The processes weren't exiting correctly and the memory footprint was growing and then crashing the docker engine.
3. I am a bad programmer.

The issue now seems to be fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Docker does not run on Windows 10 Home. For docker to run on windows, it needs Hyper-V, a virtualization framework which is only available in Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Docker Desktop has been on Windows 10 Home since [Docker Desktop Community 2.3.0.2](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/#docker-desktop-community-2302)

Answer (score -1):

If restarting docker doesn't help,

[image]

I always able to fix it by switching to `windows containers` and back

[image]

Comment: This option isn't available on Windows 10 Home